# How to create ordination plots with different species groups

Tags: r

I am thankful for any help as I am a total R noob.

I created a cca ordination plot in R with a species list and environmental variables. Now the Problem is that the species belong to different groups (mosses, lichens or herbs). I want the species points in the plots to have different colours for each group! I have a very large species list with many columns so I cannot refer to each column separately.

Column names look like this:

herb1 herb2 herb3 moss1 moss2 lichen1
the only code I have so far is this:

```
env.allspecies.cca<- vegan::cca(alpin.spec, alpin.env)

autoplot(env.allspecies.cca, title = c("CCA"))
```

I tried separating the species data set into 
alpin.spec.herb, alpin.spec.moss,alpin.spec.lichen

but I could not come to a conclusion.

How can I plot so that all herb species points have the same colour?

Or maybe I can put columns into groups and plot these groups?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful to see a sample of your data, consider using `dput()` to share a sample of your data and code you've tried so far so we can help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNz2X.jpg

```
library(vegan)

#Generate a data frame with some random species data containing 10 species
set.seed(123)#make it reproducible
random.spec            <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(100, 10, 0.5), ncol = 10))
colnames(random.spec)  <- paste0('spec', rep(1:10))

#looking at the random.spec data
head(random.spec)

  spec1 spec2 spec3 spec4 spec5 spec6 spec7 spec8 spec9 spec10
1     4     8     7     8     3     2     6     6     4      3
2     6     5     6     7     5     5     3     6     6      6
3     5     6     6     6     5     6     5     6     5      4
4     7     5     9     6     4     3     4     0     6      6
5     7     3     6     2     3     5     6     5     3      4
6     2     7     6     5     3     4     5     4     5      4

#Generate a data frame with some random environmental variables.
set.seed(123)#make it reproducible
random.env             <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, 10, 2), ncol = 10))
colnames(random.env)   <- paste0('variable', rep(1:10))

#looking at the random.env data
head(random.env)

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7 variable8 variable9
1  8.879049 12.448164  7.864353 10.852928  8.610586 10.506637 10.759279  9.017938 10.011528
2  9.539645 10.719628  9.564050  9.409857  9.584165  9.942906  8.995353  5.381662 10.770561
3 13.117417 10.801543  7.947991 11.790251  7.469207  9.914259  9.333585 12.011477  9.258680
4 10.141017 10.221365  8.542218 11.756267 14.337912 12.737205  7.962849  8.581598 11.288753
5 10.258575  8.888318  8.749921 11.643162 12.415924  9.548458  7.856418  8.623983  9.559027
6 13.430130 13.573826  6.626613 11.377281  7.753783 13.032941 10.607057 12.051143 10.663564
  variable10
1  11.987008
2  11.096794
3  10.477463
4   8.744188
5  12.721305
6   8.799481

#Apply the CCA
results                <- cca(random.spec~., random.env)

#We have 10 species and the first 5 (spec1-spec5) in the data frame belonged to one 
#group and the other 5 (spec6-spec10) to another group. We give the first 5 species 
#in the data frame a red colour and the other 5 a blue colour.
pointcolour            <- c(rep("red", 5), rep("blue", 5))

#We first create an empty plot (type = "n").
plot(results, scaling = 3, display = "species", type = "n",)

#Now we plot the species in the plot with the colours (col = pointcolour).
text(results, display = "species", cex = 1.5, col = pointcolour, scaling = 3)

#As last we plot the environmental variables.
text(results, display = "bp", add = TRUE, col = "grey40", scaling = 3)
```

Comment: Yes!! That is exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you so much!